# How to send list of maps from flutter to webapi

Tags: json, flutter, webapi

I want to send data like

[

```
 {
        "QuizTitle": "QuizList1Title", 
        "QuizDesc": "QuizList1Description",
        "Question": "List1Question1",
        "Choice1": "List1choice1",
        "Choice2": "List1choice2",
        "Choice3": "List1choice3",
        "Choice4": "List1choice4",
        "CorrectAns": "ListcorrectAns1"
    },
    {
        "QuizTitle": "QuizList2Title", 
        "QuizDesc": "QuizList2Description",
        "Question": "List2Question1",
        "Choice1": "List2choice1",
        "Choice2": "List2choice2",
        "Choice3": "List2choice3",
        "Choice4": "List2choice4",
        "CorrectAns": "ListcorrectAns2"
    },
]
```

to my webapi from flutter any leads how I can achieve this?

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/send-data

Answer (score 0):

Use the following POJO class as request. and set your parameters.

```
class Autogenerated {
  String quizTitle;
  String quizDesc;
  String question;
  String choice1;
  String choice2;
  String choice3;
  String choice4;
  String correctAns;

  Autogenerated(
      {this.quizTitle,
      this.quizDesc,
      this.question,
      this.choice1,
      this.choice2,
      this.choice3,
      this.choice4,
      this.correctAns});

  Autogenerated.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    quizTitle = json['QuizTitle'];
    quizDesc = json['QuizDesc'];
    question = json['Question'];
    choice1 = json['Choice1'];
    choice2 = json['Choice2'];
    choice3 = json['Choice3'];
    choice4 = json['Choice4'];
    correctAns = json['CorrectAns'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['QuizTitle'] = this.quizTitle;
    data['QuizDesc'] = this.quizDesc;
    data['Question'] = this.question;
    data['Choice1'] = this.choice1;
    data['Choice2'] = this.choice2;
    data['Choice3'] = this.choice3;
    data['Choice4'] = this.choice4;
    data['CorrectAns'] = this.correctAns;
    return data;
  }
}
```

After that use `json.encode()` to encode object into json and using dio send the api request.